# Open files via an elevated context menu program

Tags: windows

So I've created in context menu an "open with Ollydbg" option.How can I run olly as an administrator from that point on?What command or arguments should I use?I run into a "ShellExecuteEx" command but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Olly executable's properties.
2. Click the *Compatibility* tab.
3. Check *Run this program as an administrator*.

`ShellExecuteEx` is an API function, not a command. You could use it if you were developing an application to run other EXEs with elevated privileges.

If you want to run any program with elevated privileges from a command line, create a `sudo.cmd` file in any directory in your PATH:

```
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

Then type for example `sudo notepad C:\example.txt` to open `C:\example.txt` in elevated Notepad. ([original source](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/142153-sudo-equivalent-for-windows-vista7/))

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [this another answer](https://superuser.com/a/640599) won't work if the command line contains double quotes and/or ends with `\"`, e.g. `copy c:\foo.txt "c:\Program Files\"`. A modified version like below fixes that.

```
@echo off
set str=%*
set str=%str:\"="%      
set str=%str:"=""%
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%str%", (Len("%str%") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```