# Run dialog "run as admin" option

Tags: windows-7, uac, run-dialog

Is this a Windows 7 feature?

[image: Create new task: Create this task with administrative privileges.]

Is there any way I can start whatever I type there as admin always if I have UAC on?

I don't want to have to configure every app that I want to start as admin, or use the runas command. I've searched and multiple people said it's not possible, is the run command this limited?

Also, I don't want to run Explorer itself as admin to circumvent this.

Comment: I think the problem is you want UAC, but you don't want it to ask for admin rights, and you don't want to configure applications. They're all somewhat contradictory statements, what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I'm fine with displaying UAC prompt, i want to run everything inside the Run Dialog as admin, i don't care if it prompts or not, i just don't want to configure every app that i may run there to run as admin, is this not possible at all?

Comment: I understand - unfortunately I don't believe there is a way with the `Run` dialog, which I agree is annoying. The Start Menu you can with the solution in my post, or you can configure applications manually as per @LPChip's answer, otherwise I think you're out of luck though.

Comment: @Jonno , one of the apps is taskmgr, windows doesn't seem me to allow to change the "compatibility" tab on windows files, am i stuck with this also? http://i.imgur.com/3GWo86L.png

Comment: Odd, I'm not quite sure, I know network shared items don't allow it. There may be a registry workaround (information [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/cannot-change-compatibility-mode/0ad8bcf1-9e62-4190-9a3f-1469631ec4c9)), it may be because of the permissions for this particular EXE (Owned by system rather than your account or the admin group).

Comment: @Jonno Thanks for the link, very useful info, taking control of the .exe didn't allow me to change the compatibility tab anyway, so, i did it from regedit as "RUNASADMIN", everytime i run taskmgr it runs as admin now, only problem is Ctrl Shift Esc doesn't do nothing, god bless windows lol. Edit: Neither does Ctrl Alt Del + clicking on task manager.

Comment: Open PowerShell as admin (DOS prompt would work too, but this is 2016). Run stuff you want as admin from there. Test it out with `notepad`. You'll see it's admin. This becomes a super-run, but you constrain the ability to that box.

Comment: @SomeNickName Converting to an answer to benefit others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That particular screen is from Task Manager's `File` -> `Run New Task` and exists since Windows 7.

[image]

This check box doesn't exist on the standard 'Run...' box from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, although you can get to this screen by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> if you wish.

Otherwise, you can run things from the Start Menu as admin by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can disable UAC and use an administrator account to remove this protection, although this is a fairly dangerous practice as you will have no defence against any program with a malicious intent. You can find the option under `User Accounts` in the control panel.

More information in this question I made [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1029295/is-there-a-faster-way-to-open-a-process-as-administrator-with-uac-enabled).

Comment: I don't have that checkbox on the taskmgr new task, it wouldn't be useful in this case 'cause i'm trying to reduce the time i spent running as admin, but, it's not there, running windows 7 Ultimate 64-bits.

Comment: Nevermind, the option is there IF i execute taskmgr as admin, which is not ideal for what i want...

Comment: You can use autohotkey to fire this key for you when you type win+r

Comment: The Start Menu trick is what I used. I had to train myself to stop using Win+R and hit the Windows key instead. When you hit the Windows key you can immediately type and it will filter application names (as long as their locations are indexed). Then when your application is highlighted, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to launch as admin. Now instead of Win+R > cmd.exe > enter, I use Win > 'co' (let it autocomplete) > Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run every program as administrator, yet you do not want to disable UAC.

Well, this is contradicting already. If every program ran as administrator, UAC would in essence be doing nothing. Explorer itself is a program and would thus also be run as admin, and any program launched or otherwise will run as admin, so if you want to accomplish this, disable UAC.

If you do not want to run every program as admin, you will have to configure a program to run as admin one way or the other. There are various methods you can use though. Jonno gave a way to manually start a program as admin, but if you want to configure it for any program, then this answer will work better.

## Configure an individual program to always run as administrator

First, if you don't already have a shortcut either in the start menu or on your desktop (take the one where you will be launching it from) you will have to create the shortcut first. Now, right click the shortcut and choose `properties`

Go to the `Security` tab and check `Always run this program as Administrator`

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> and you're done for that program.

Opening the shortcut the normal way will now provide you with the UAC dialog to confirm you want to run the program as Administrator, or no to abort launching the program.

Comment: I want to run every program as admin from the Run Dialog.
One of these programs is taskmgr, and windows apparently disabled the configuration you suggested on windows files that i already tried.

Comment: @Jonno Feel free to edit my question, i think i explained myself enough for you to improve it ;)

Comment: @SomeNickName Ah, if windows does not show you the `Compatibility` tab, then you will have to manually create a shortcut to the executable and use `cmd.exe /c "c:\path\program.exe"` This will allow you to do many things to the program and shortcut, including pinning it to your taskbar if desired.

Comment: @SomeNickName Reading the comments, it seems a policy is in place on your computer which prevents task manager and access to the compatibility tab. This might prevent you from doing this answer then.

Comment: Windows does show me the security tab, however that option is on the "Compatibility" tab, which is greyed out completely for system files, i've tried taking control of the .exe, same thing, changed compatibility layer manually through registry now it always opens as admin, however, Ctrl Shift Esc doesn't do nothing, neither does Ctrl Alt Del + click on task manager.
Thanks for the answer, i see i got limited options here.

Comment: @SomeNickName is your computer in a domain and thus controlled by policies? If not, then you might have a policy problem that can be repaired to fix the issue.

Comment: Computer isn't on a domain, how can i check if i have a policy problem?
Edit: To clarify my previous comment, compatibility tab is greyed out, i changed it manually through the registry, the change worked and task manager runs as admin always, however the shortcut Ctrl Shift Esc doesn't do nothing, which afaik it's normal in this case from what i've searched, if you were talking about a policy problem 'cause of the security tab option you mentioned, then idk.

Comment: @SomeNickName open a command prompt as administrator and run the following command: `gpupdate /force` this should restore settings. A reboot may be required afterwards.

Comment: i'll do it but what is this going to do specifically? Edit: Already done it

Comment: It'll stop any problems regarding policies. It refreshes your local policies. You might now be able to press CTRL-ESC etc to bring task manager up, and have access to the security tab, etc. If it still doesn't work, then something is wrong in your profile and it needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Ctrl Shift Esc only doesn't work if i manually change compatibility mode to "RUNASADMIN" in regedit for task manager (what i said i did above), if i remove it, it works again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I generally do:

Open PowerShell as admin (DOS prompt would work too, but this is 2016). Run stuff you want as admin from there. Test it out with `notepad`. You'll see it's admin. This becomes a super-run, but you constrain the ability to that box.

Comment: Upvoting because of a nice and inexpensive workaround to the Run Dialog, saves a few keystrokes and also a uac popup for everything i run.

Comment: There's no DOS in Windows NT.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You know what a DOS prompt is. Don't be a smart alec. If you want to go there, then, there's no Windows NT anymore at all. End of discussion.